# Interpret "plain text" as utf-8 text in python

Tags: python, string, text, encoding, utf-8

I have a text file  with text that should have been interpreted as utf-8 but wasn't (it was given to me this way). 
Here is an example of a typical line of the file:

> \u30ed\u30f3\u30c9\u30f3\u5728\u4f4f

which should have been:

> ロンドン在住

Now, I can do it manually on python by typing the following in the command line:

```
>>> h1 = u'\u30ed\u30f3\u30c9\u30f3\u5728\u4f4f'    
>>> print h1
ロンドン在住
```

which gives me what I want. Is there a way that I can do this automatically? I've tried doing stuff like this

```
>>> f = codecs.open('testfile.txt', encoding='utf-8')
>>> h = f.next()
>>> print h
\u30ed\u30f3\u30c9\u30f3\u5728\u4f4f
```

I've also tried with the 'encode' and 'decode' functions, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as plain text, and there's really no such thing as UTF-8 text, either. Text is an abstraction. UTF-8 is an encoding of characters into bytes. Also, if the file actually contains backslashes, it's completely different from putting backslashes between double-quotes in a Python source file. That's a completely separate encoding step. If you want ロ in your file, then put ロ in your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\u30ed\u30f3\u30c9\u30f3\u5728\u4f4f` is not UTF8; it's using the python unicode escape format. Use the `unicode_escape` codec instead:

```
>>> print '\u30ed\u30f3\u30c9\u30f3\u5728\u4f4f'.decode('unicode_escape')
ロンドン在住
```

Here is the UTF-8 encoding of the above phrase, for comparison:

```
>>> '\u30ed\u30f3\u30c9\u30f3\u5728\u4f4f'.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8')
'\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x83\x89\xe3\x83\xb3\xe5\x9c\xa8\xe4\xbd\x8f'
```

Note that the data decoded with `unicode_escape` are treated as Latin-1 for anything that's not a recognised Python escape sequence.

Be careful however; it may be you are really looking at *JSON-encoded data*, which uses the same notation for specifying character escapes. Use `json.loads()` to decode actual JSON data; JSON strings with such escapes are delimited with `"` quotes and are usually part of larger structures (such as JSON lists or objects).